# Syllable emphasis in "caricature"

Tags: pronunciation

Does anyone pronounce caricature with the emphasis on the 2nd syllable rather than the first?  Example:  caRIcature vs. CAricature

Comment: Never on the 2nd syllable.  But sometimes with emphasis on the final (4th) syllable - caricaTURE!

Comment: @Dan I saw an episode of the reality-TV show *Botched* where a woman had plastic surgery in order to look more like her [*car-i-ca-chuuuuure*](https://youtu.be/1UC0r0ZYxbY?t=19) (at about 19 seconds in).

Answer (score 2):

The OED only lists one pronunciation, with a primary stress on the first syllable and a secondary stress on the last:

> *caricature*, n. /ˈkarɪkəˌtjʊə/

The Merriam-Webster dictionary lists several variants, but all have the same stress pattern as the OED:

> *caricature*, n. \ˈker-i-kə-ˌchu̇r, -ˌchər, -ˌtyu̇r, -ˌtu̇r, -ˈka-ri-\

If you're not familiar with stress markings, the symbol \ˈ\ precedes the syllable with main stress in a word, and the symbol \ˌ\ precedes any syllable with secondary stress.

This is not to say that nobody ever pronounces it this way, but it is not a commonly accepted pronunciation.  It may be spoken as an unintentional error, or it may be done for [humorous effect.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8VHzzBWmPQ)